# What are the grades of Italian pasta?

Tags: food-science, pasta, grade

I'm a Russian student. I'm writing a report about Italian pasta. There is no information on the Russian web sites, so guys, help me, please. I need to learn more about the grade/quality of pasta. What are the exact grades(e.g. in Russia we have three grades of pasta. it depends on wheat quality)?. Any information will help me. Maybe, you know some kind of sources where i can find the information. Any books?

Comment: Can you explain what the Russian classification describes exactly? If you're referring to the numbers like spaghetti no. 3, no. 4.. then I'm afraid there's no universal meaning and every manufacturer has its own grading.

Comment: @DavidP The classification depends on the type of wheat flour(durum, soft,). Also, there are three groups (like A, B,C) and each group has a grade that depends on the amount of ash (the first grade, the second one..)I need to find some official documents, science articles

Answer (score 2):

After the clarifying comments, I think the question now boils down to reading the nutrition table and to the Italian classification of flour, in particular, durum since it's the most used for the pasta production. I can refer to the table on the Italian Wikipedia, where it's compared with the US classification. https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farina#Sfarinati_di_grano_duro

However, also concerning food, Italy is the land of exceptions. For instance, fresh pasta usually has a part of soft wheat and some regional types may use flours from other cereals at all. Not to mention the pasta for the gluten-free market.

Exceptions do not mean that something can be called pasta in a region and not in another. The regulations are the same for the whole country and are here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasta#Italy

Comment: thank you! You mentioned that Italy has exceptions. Can you explain this, please? Does it mean that different provinces in Italy have their own laws of the pasta production?

Comment: I just meant that some regional types use other cereals. Didn't mean that you can call something pasta in a region and not in another region. Anyway I'm editing my answer with a link.